# Button to update the text in a search field but entering several values in sequence?

Tags: javascript, html

With this code we can send a single value to the search field. Now, taking into account this example, how do we insert more values in sequence with the same button, for example: value 1, value 2, value 3 ...?

http://jsfiddle.net/g506bxL4/1/

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function setValue() {
    
        document.getElementById('bbb').value = "valor 1";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply make a counter:

```js
var valor = 0;

function setValue() {
  valor++;
  document.getElementById('bbb').value = "valor " + valor;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not getting results, maybe someone can change the code at jsfiddle.net/g506bxL4/1, just change and save to get a new page and address.

Comment: Attention please, the values cannot be the same, they must be different, for example Value 1, health, fun, yesterday 5 ... and the previous value must also be erased and the new one must appear; that is, clicking Value 1 should give way to health, health should give way to fun, and so on. Maybe someone can change the code at jsfiddle.net/g506bxL4/1, just change and save to get a new page and address.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You said "how do we insert more values in *sequence* with the same *button*". Now you say different values and clicking on input...

Comment: I am sorry if it was poorly explained, is that I have to translate it into English.

Comment: On the other hand, I never said that I wanted the values ​​to be all visible in the field or to change the number and keep the same text. By saying in sequence, I only meant to say that one should replace the other (a sequence is a succession of units).

Answer (score 0):

These are the two solutions, one inserts the values ​​randomly and the other inserts in order. They are both working perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/62wLqz37/1/

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
const myValues = ['Decoration', 'Health', 'Fun', 'Yesterday 4'];

function setValue() {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myValues.length); ;
    document.getElementById('bbb').value = myValues[randomNum];
}
</script
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bpaL5hy/

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
const myValues = ['Decoration', 'Health', 'Fun', 'Yesterday 4'];
let myInd = 0;

function setValue() {
    document.getElementById('bbb').value = myValues[myInd];
    myInd = myInd >= (myValues.length - 1) ? 0 : myInd+1;
}
</script>
```